# Software readings gone from Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

About a month ago I added 5 of my all-time favorite blog posts from technical bloggers to the "Reading" part of my Careers profile. Today, as I logged in to show a colleague of mine how much better than LinkedIn Careers is, *the blog posts that I linked to were gone*. What up?

Comment: Sorry for OT, but how can you compare LI to Careers? Careers is just a CV, whereas LI is more of social network...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. There was a bug preventing those from appearing on the edit screen for your profile – would you try it again? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! Thanks!